# Is this preg_replace exploitable?

Tags: php, code-injection, exploit

I'm looking to exploit this preg_replace call:

```
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '__', $str);
```

I can control both $str and $pattern variables, but I'm not sure this is enough to inject 
arbitrary PHP code. Some idea? :)

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Why are you asking for an exploit? That is not the intention of this website to help exploiting code.

Comment: What are `$pattern` and `$str`?  Exploitable how?  Is the result going into a database?  Shell?  File?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you control both inputs, then obviously it's not exploitable, as there's no user-controlled input.

Comment: Think of this: $pattern = $_GET['pattern']; $str = $_GET['str']; $str = preg_replace($pattern, '__', $str); I'm trying to searching for a method to inject arbitrary PHP leveraging the "e" modifier...Something like this vulnerability: http://www.madirish.net/195

Comment: @user2041321: Why are you letting the user input a regex?  What is your ultimate goal here?

Answer (score 5):

`preg_replace` is only exploitable if the `e` modifier is used. This means that the `$replacement` string is evaluated as PHP code. Since you provide no way for the `$replacement` to be changed by the remote user, it is not vulnerable to exploits.

Comment: nice interpretation of an ambiguous question

Comment: Thanks @lonesomeday, I know that, and this is the reason why I posted the question: to know if someone knows a workaround to inject PHP code even though the $replacement isn't controllable by user input. I was thinking to something like preg_replace("/eval\(phpcode\)/e", "__", "phpcode"). In other words, way to inject PHP code into the $pattern or $subject parameter!

Comment: if you allow users to set those variables, then yes, otherwise no

Comment: @user2041321 If you don't provide any way for the user-supplied text to enter the string that is executed (and you don't), there is no way for arbitrary code to be executed. Neither `$pattern` nor `$subject` nor any matches will be executed unless you explicitly say so.

Comment: @Dagon when I say "I can control both $str and $pattern variables" I mean I'm a remote user that I can set those variable. You say yes, so how can I exploit it?